# Commenting system with jQuery, Ajax & PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, comments

There are 50 images on which you can Add / Delete comment , Which is a better way for implementation ?

> 1) Create an individual form for each image . Add the data to form and
>   post it ? (50 forms would be created & 50 for deleting i think )
>
> 2) Use Jquery to select the text from the text box and ID and then
>   post it using Ajax ?

I think the site

http://pinterest.com/

is using Approach 1 and

Facebook

us using Approach 2 ?
Which one is better ?

Comment: I used to use the second way.

Comment: @RicardoLohmann -Would it be possible if you could share some tutorial for this approach ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would use the second approach, it's more modern and you don't have to reload the page for an action.

But this is not a question with an definitive answer, because both ways will work fine.

**Update:** This is a tutorial for deleting a comment http://papermashup.com/jquery-ajax-delete/

With adding one it's basicially the same approach, but you send the referencing image id and the comment text.

Comment: Would it be possible if you could share some tutorial for this approach ?

Answer (score 0):

For method 2, something like this will work:

```
//LISTEN FOR YOUR SUBMIT COMMENT BUTTON TO FIRE
$("#commentButton").live('submit', function(e) {

    //GET COMMENT
    com = $("#commentField").text();

    //POST COMMENT
    $.post("commentsystem.php", { user: user, comment: com} );

});
```